# Converting a specific column data in .csv to text using Python pandas

Tags: list, csv, pandas

I have a .csv file like below where all the contents are text

```
col1             Col2
My name          Arghya
The Big Apple    Fruit
```

I am able to read this csv using pd.read_csv(index_col=False, header=None).
How do I combine all the three rows in Col1 into a list separated by a full stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need convert column values to `list`:

```
print (df.Col1.tolist())
#alternative solution
#print (list(df.Col1))
['This is Apple', 'I am in Mumbai', 'I like rainy day']
```

And then `join` values in `list` - output is `string`:

```
a = '.'.join(df.Col1.tolist())
print (a)
This is Apple.I am in Mumbai.I like rainy day
```

---

```
print (df)
                  0      1
0              Col1   Col2
1     This is Apple  Fruit
2    I am in Mumbai  Great
3  I like rainy day  Flood


print (list(df.loc[:, 0]))
#alternative
#print (list(df[0]))
['Col1', 'This is Apple', 'I am in Mumbai', 'I like rainy day']
```

Comment: Please note that there is no header i.e. Col1 and Col2 are NOT there in the .csv file.

Comment: I add solution for it.

Comment: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tolist' ..... I am using Python 3.5 and Anaconda Spyder IDE.

Comment: You need select first column - `df.loc[:, 0]`

Comment: TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [0] of <class 'int'>

Comment: What is `df.columns.tolist()` ?